# sorting dataframe with conditions and producing newer dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

current dataframe looks as :

```
uniqueID       Transaction date      Action date    Action Taken       sms_sent_date
  33               21-05-2022          21-05-2022       login            20-05-2022
  33               21-05-2022          21-05-2022       login            20-05-2022
  33               21-05-2022          21-05-2022       openedPage       21-05-2022
  33               21-05-2022          21-05-2022       openedPage       20-05-2022
  33               21-05-2022          21-05-2022       pay_success      19-05-2022
  33               21-05-2022          21-05-2022       pay_success      19-05-2022
  33               21-05-2022          25-05-2022       login            23-05-2022
  22               16-05-2022          16-05-2022       login            15-05-2022
  22               16-05-2022          16-05-2022       openedPage       15-05-2022
  22               16-05-2022          16-05-2022       pay_success      15-05-2022
  44                                                      login          28-05-2022
  44                                                      login          28-05-2022
```

new dataframe has be created that looks as :

```
 uniqueID       Transaction date      Action date    Action Taken       sms_sent_date   count_of_action   nu_of_time_action_taken   count_of_unique_days_when_sms_sent
  33               21-05-2022          21-05-2022       login            20-05-2022       1                           2                        4
  33               21-05-2022          21-05-2022       openedPage       21-05-2022       1                             2                        -
  33               21-05-2022          21-05-2022       pay_success      19-05-2022       1                              2                        -
  22               16-05-2022          16-05-2022       login            15-05-2022       1                             1                            1
  22               16-05-2022          16-05-2022       openedPage       15-05-2022       1                                    1                       -
  22               16-05-2022          16-05-2022       pay_success      15-05-2022       1                                   1                       -
  44                                                      login          28-05-2022       -                             -                       1
```

*Transaction date should be equal to action date

*if action date is greater than transaction date it should be removed

Comment: Could you explain the details of the requirements and show what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to 1- remove duplicates, 2- ensure transaction date == action date, 3- keep NA dates:

Use boolean indexing:

```
# row is not duplicated
m1 = ~df.duplicated()

# dates are equal
m2 = df['Transaction date'] == df['Action date']

# date is NA
m3 = df['Transaction date'].isna()

# conditions 1 AND (2 OR 3)
df[m1&(m2|m3)]
```

output:

```
    uniqueID Transaction date Action date Action Taken sms_sent_date
0         33       21-05-2022  21-05-2022        login    20-05-2022
2         33       21-05-2022  21-05-2022   openedPage    21-05-2022
3         33       21-05-2022  21-05-2022   openedPage    20-05-2022
4         33       21-05-2022  21-05-2022  pay_success    19-05-2022
7         22       16-05-2022  16-05-2022        login    15-05-2022
8         22       16-05-2022  16-05-2022   openedPage    15-05-2022
9         22       16-05-2022  16-05-2022  pay_success    15-05-2022
10        44              NaN         NaN        login    28-05-2022
```

Comment: appreciate your effort..! i am looking for the last three columns in the output

Comment: Then slice with: `[['Action date', 'Action Taken', 'sms_sent_date']]`

Comment: can u please elaborate. any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: `df.loc[m1&(m2|m3), ['Action date', 'Action Taken', 'sms_sent_date']]`